# Perforce: find previous submitted changelist number via command line

Tags: command, perforce, p4v

Suppose I know a changelist that has some issues with the build.
I want to know the previously submitted changelist so that I can sync to it.

I know a way to get it from p4v.
I want to know how to get it via the p4 command so that I can add it to the bash script.

Ex. 
Changelist previous to 553682 is 553642

changelist number is managed by perforce across all the code base so i cannot reduce a number and take it.

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract 1.  If changelist `@553682` is the broken one, syncing to `@553681` will give you the revisions prior to those in that changelist.

This works even if change 553681 doesn't exist (i.e. the number got skipped), or if it's a changelist that affects a different part of the codebase.  When you use a changelist as a revision specifier it defines the upper bound (in changelist terms) of all the revisions that will be affected by the operation; since changelists are strictly increasing, changelist numbers are always comparable in a straightforward way, similar to timestamps (i.e. you can sync to a particular point in time even if nothing was submitted at that precise nanosecond; you'll just get whatever was current as of that point in time).

tl;dr yes, just "reduce the number and take it," it'll work.